# Retrieving elements from a join with into Entity Framework

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, join

I have this code:

```
private IQueryable<Trip> GetTripWithBreaksAndPassengers(DB_Context context, long id)
{
    return from t in context.trip
           where t.Id == id
           join breaks in context.breaks on t.Id equals breaks.tripid into breaksJoin
           join drivers in context.drivers on t.Id equals drivers.tripid into driversJoin
           select new Trip() { TripBreaks = ?, TripDrivers = ?};
}
```

For my `Trip` specified by an `id`, I want to return a list of `Breaks` and `Drivers`.

My `Trip` object has two fields which are lists, `TripBreaks` and `TripDrivers`:

```
public virtual List<TripBreak> TripBreaks { get; set; }
public virtual List<TripDriver> TripDrivers { get; set; }
```

I want both of them to be returned as part of a `Trip` - I am expecting `breaksJoin` and `driversJoin` to hold those specific results, but if queried like

```
TripDrivers = driversJoin.ToList()
```

it will throw an error.

How should I use those join results to get the elements held?

Comment: TripDrivers = GetTripWithBreaksAndPassengers(ctx, 100).ToList(); will give you your navigation properties. BTW, you shouldn't pass in your db context, inject it instead.

Answer (score 0):

Explicit joins in a EF project are a code smell.

You should be able to use navigation properties and `Include()` to get the data you want, something like this.

```
var result = context.trip.Include(t => t.Breaks).Include(t => t.Drivers).FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == id);
```

This will get you all the related entities in one go.

Adjust property names accordingly, since you didn't share your model classes.

Comment: Include and join do the same thing

Comment: Only in a very rudimentary sense. `Include()` operates on a navigation property, which may be anything like table splitting, TPC/TPH, owned entities etc. One shouldn't need to remember which column to join on, `Include()` takes care of that for you.